# Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2, problem with labels

Tags: python, tensorflow

Cannot handle this problem:

```
Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
     [[{{node Squeeze}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_133866]
Function call stack:
train_function
```

while running this bunch of code:

```
# Define the number of epochs.
epochs = 1
# Callback function to check transcription on the val set.
validation_callback = CallbackEval(validation_dataset)
# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    callbacks=[validation_callback],
)
```

The problem I guess is here:

```
#create dataset objects:
batch_size = 32
# Define the training dataset

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (list(df_train["file"]), list(df_train["text"]))
)
train_dataset = (
    train_dataset.map(encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .padded_batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)
# Define the validation dataset
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (list(df_val["file"]), list(df_val["text"]))
)
validation_dataset = (
    validation_dataset.map(encode_single_sample, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    .padded_batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)
```

df_train contains 2 columns - file and text. The text is in Kazakh language (Cyrillic). Is that can be a problem? Please help

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @Gulnaz What is the shape of the labels and the training data?